# Показать страницу 404 без перенаправления

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

У меня есть сайт, на котором статья показывается по ее ID. Что-то типо такого:

```
mysite.ru/article.php?id=123
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при несуществующей статье мне показывалась страница, указанная в .htaccess подобным образом:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
```

Но линк оставался прежним. Каким боком это можно провернуть, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Надо возложить всю обработку УРЛ на скрипт, а не htaccess. Получаете УРЛ, если страницы с таким УРЛ нет, отправляете нужные заголовки и формируете контент 404 страницы вручную. Псевдокод:

    if( $site->page_load($url)
    {
        header("Status: 200 OK");
        $view->render_page();
    }
    else
    {
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        $view->render_page404();
    }

Comment: В php ООП как-то убого реализовано, в отличие от той же самой Java. 
+ я не раз уже слышал, что при использовании ООП очень сильно падает производительность. Поэтому я использую процедурный метод, даже вопреки своему желанию. 
К тому же, я не хотел в это дело ввязывать .htaccess. Но как тогда реально определить несуществующий файл, и выдать ошибку?

Comment: @vital_viza, вы "слышали про падение производительности", или столкнулись с ней? (я уж молчу, что этот пример пишется за пять минут и в ФП-парадигме)

Comment: Слышал. Сталкиваться не приходилось, потому что пока нет столь крупных проектов. Но рисковать не стоит. 
+ я ООП в РНР не люблю. Поэтому использовать не собираюсь

Comment: @vital_viza, но я же написал, что это псевдокод, пишите так, как вам удобно. Несуществующий файл? Вы чтоли в файлах храните страницы? Если да, то file_exist() вам в помощь

if( file_exist($path))
{
    header("Status: 200 OK");
    $view->load_page($path);
}
else
{
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    $view->load_page($path_to_404_html);
}

Comment: @MDJHD, моя CMS шаблонная. И некоторые особенные разделы я храню в отдельных файлах, используя общий шаблон. Я, пожалуй, остановлюсь на своем варианте решения задачи, так как он отлично вписывается в структуру моей CMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, я думаю, что как такового способа узнать стандартную страницу ошибки 404 нет, поэтому я проделал такой финт:

В .htaccess прописал такие строки, которые перехватывают основные ошибки:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors.php?code=400
ErrorDocument 403 /errors.php?code=403
ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php?code=404
ErrorDocument 405 /errors.php?code=405
ErrorDocument 408 /errors.php?code=408
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.php?code=500
ErrorDocument 502 /errors.php?code=502
ErrorDocument 504 /errors.php?code=504
```

Тут все понятно. Скрипт errors.php получает код ошибки через GET и выводит нужный нам текст

А вот функция, которая создает ошибку. Любую, которая мне будет нужна

```
 function throw_error($code = 404)
 {
  //проверяем, отправлены ли заголовки
  if (!headers_sent($filename, $linenum)) { 
   $code = int($code);
   //коды основных ошибок
   $codes = array(
    400 => "400 Bad Request",
    403 => "403 Forbidden",
    404 => "404 Not Found",
    405 => "405 Method Not Allowed",
    408 => "408 Request Timeout",
    500 => "500 Internal Server Error",
    502 => "502 Bad Gateway",
    504 => "504 Gateway Timeout",
   );

   //убеждаемся, что такая ошибка есть в массиве
   $status = "404 Not Found";
   if (isset($codes[$code]))
   {
    $status = $codes[$code];
   }
   else
   {
    $code = 404;
   }

   //отправляем заголовки
   $sapi_name = php_sapi_name();
   if ($sapi_name == 'cgi' || $sapi_name == 'cgi-fcgi') {
       header('Status: '.$status);
   } else {
       header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' '.$status);
   }
   /*
    Костыль, знаю, зато работает. Вывод страницы с ошибкой
    Не include, потому что на страницах используются константы, которые имеют широкую область видимости.
   */

   echo file_get_contents('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/errors.php?code='.$code);

   exit();  
  }
  else
  {
   //если заголовки уже отправлены, говорим об этом
   echo "Sorry... Headers already sent on line $linenum";
   exit();
  }
 }
```

Comment: и этот человек говорит о производительности...

    echo file_get_contents('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/errors.php?code='.$code);

Comment: @eicto ох щи

Comment: @eicto, я бы не кидал этот код сюда, если бы мне не нужен был совет.

+ если все таки ООП в РНР не столь производительна, как многие утверждают, то один раз воспользоваться таким костылем не особо снизит производительность.

И к тому же я сказал, что в коде используются константы, которые при инклуде страницы с ошибкой выдали бы множество нотисов из-за этого. Поэтому я воспользовался подобными костылями.

Переписывать весь код, ради какой-то проверки на существование статьи или какой либо другой записи... Ну, знаете... Как-то лень)

Comment: @vital_viza вы серьезно? У вас движок перезапускает сам себя и еще напрягает сеть (пусть и лупбек) и сервер. И еще наверняка не fcgi и php каждый раз заново инициализируется. `microtime(true)` и вперед.

> И к тому же я сказал, что в коде используются константы, которые при инклуде страницы с ошибкой выдали бы множество нотисов из-за этого.

Что это за движок, которому константы мешают выдавать сообщение об ошибке?

> Переписывать весь код, ради какой-то проверки на существование статьи или какой либо другой записи...

Поэтому его стоит переписать для удобства работы.

Comment: Справился с инклудом. Так что все вроде бы должно работать нормально